# Access Metadata for a Derived View other than the tree View in Denodo

Tags: denodo

I am using Denodo VDP 5.5.
I have a very complex Derived View to understand. I am able to get Tree View of the View. But since it is very BIG, it is very hard to understand it. Is there a way to access metadata for that VIEW or get the tree structure in an EXCEL format?

Basically I want to get the relationship of the VIEWS among them.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Advanced VQL Guide](https://community.denodo.com/docs/view/document/Denodo%20Express/Denodo%205.5/Advanced%20VQL%20Guide), 12.3.14:

> 12.3.14 VIEW_DEPENDENCIES
>
> Description
>
> The stored procedure VIEW_DEPENDENCIES returns a list of the dependencies of one or more derived views (not base views).
>
> This procedure allows you to obtain programmatically the same information that the
> Administration Tool displays in the “Tree view” dialog of a derived view.

I think you need to be on Denodo 5.5 20151005 update ( see [here](https://community.denodo.com/answers/question/details?questionId=90670000000L5RtAAK&title=Is%20there%20a%20way%20to%20force%20a%20dependency%20check%3F) )

Although this doesn't give you the tree view in excel, you can use the output to put the dependencies into a format that you want.